# Is it possible to find out what a specific output window mentioned thread is about?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I've got a very strange case. When I'm debugging a specific application I'm getting a thread info in the output window of visual studio:

> Der Thread 0x4c08 hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.

Now what I'm confused about is....I'm not using any threads in my program. What I'm doing are multiple database connections to sql server and to linked servers (also sql).

Is there any way to find out what part of the program is creating these omnious threads? (the code itself in total is a few thousand lines long and has a few loops, ... so stepping through each command is not really a possibility).

Comment: It could be the debugger itself. If you run your program outside the debugger you can see how many threads are used from Task Manager. It could be other things too. The *garbage collector* though uses its own threads. Calls to `BeginInvoke` essentially start a new thread. You can see what's going on by pausing execution during debugging and by looking at the `Parallel Stacks` debugger window (Debugger > Windows > ...).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The garbage collector is a possiblity there then. As I'm calling it manually (or more speeding it up as I else get into some memory troubles in the mai loop). that is a good possibility then for what that thread is about.

Comment: Calling the GC manually is a smell. You shouldn't have to do that, unless something creates temporary objects needlessly, eg string operations like splitting, or adding a lot of items to a container without first specifying a capacity. Lists for example grow by doulbing and copying their internal buffer. If you add 1M items, you get 2^19 reallocations of some increasingly big buffers. I wouldn't bother about the thread, I'd be really concerned about memory consumption though

Comment: There's a window for that. [How to view threads in the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/walkthrough-debugging-a-multithreaded-application?view=vs-2017).

Comment: What's "ominous" about threads exiting with a successful exit code?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If you don't use multitasking in your program and you see dozens of thread exited messages.....that is a bit unsettling. Thus either some automatec threads or there is something in the code that does not work as you thought it would.

Comment: I see thread exit messages all the time when running moderately complex programs, even when I'm not doing anything "threading" related in my own code. My usual instinct is to ignore them. I'm in a managed runtime with a large library of assemblies (the framework) I can pull in. That something I haven't written might be using threads to get it's work done isn't something I'm spending energy looking into.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that is true if you don't know if something uses threads or not. That is or was the problem in my case. I KNEW the program didn't use ANY threads at all. Thus the "Thread exists" were quite unexpected to see and notice. And unusual + unexpected mostly means troubles when it comes to programming in my experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every .NET application has at least one main thread:) Your exit code means that thread was finished successfully. You can enable threads window during debug and see what happens (*Debug-Windows-Threads*)

Comment: In this case its with high propability the garbage collector. (pavel mentioned it in a comment and as I manually "start" it it is very probable).The window itself helps a lot if it comes to multiple threads thus in essence my question is answered with it.